# MySQL Metrics on Web Application

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jakarta-ee, web

I have a web based application (J2EE) based on MySQL. I need to monitor the MySQL DB instance as in the health of the server, status, different parameters, the event in case mySQL goes down and etc.

Overall I am trying to monitor the MySQL at my application end as it is a network monitoring application.

In my knowledge the MySQL provides a user based interface for monitoring the MySQL instances (something  a kind of a console) which shows all these information. Now can I have that same information exposed from MySQL so that I can consume that at my application and show the statistics on my application rather than replying on the MySQL user based interface.

Possible way of exposing the information can be XML or if I have a library which provides an API to get this information, I can build up a small File/XML based structure to get the value from that API.

This seems a bit interesting to me because you should be able to monitor the database your application is using and different metrics of DB should be available for analysis purpose and monitoring purpose.

What can be the possible way out.